# Mercurial Fetcher and AUTOREV

Tags: mercurial, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'm trying to get a bitbake file to pull down the latest revision of a mercurial repo when it builds. It's unfortunately undocumented (https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#auto-revisions), though there are a few mailing list posts on the topic. None of my attempts to recreate their methods have panned out.

This is what the .bb file looks like:

```
###############################################################################
# Variables for locations.
###############################################################################
SRC_URI = "hg://foo//bar/foobar/test;rev=${SRCREV};protocol=ssh;branch=default;module=root"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"

# Sources are downloaded to an hg subdirectory when pulling a repo.
S = "${WORKDIR}/hg"

###############################################################################
# The version of the library we're going to install.
###############################################################################
# Set PV to SRCPV so bitbake knows it should always check SRC_URI for a new
# version of the application.
PV = "${SRCPV}"
PR = "r0"
PE = "1"
```

And here's the relevant part of the output error:

```
/usr/bin/env hg up -C -r AUTOINC
| DEBUG: Python function base_do_unpack finished
| DEBUG: Python function do_unpack finished
| ERROR: Function failed: Fetcher failure: Fetch command failed with exit code 255, output:
| abort: unknown revision 'AUTOINC'!
| 
NOTE: recipe test-1_AUTOINC+AUTOINC-r0: task do_unpack: Failed
DEBUG: Teardown for bitbake-worker
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 361 tasks of which 359 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/intern/git/poky/meta/recipes-core/test/test_0.0.1.bb, do_unpack
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

The problem seems to be that AUTOREV is resolving to AUTOINC instead of a hash number. Any thoughts on what I can change to fix this?

Comment: The AUTOREV feature isn't available for mercurial SCM as stated in mega manual: [5.21. Using an External SCM](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#platdev-appdev-srcrev).

Comment: That's a bummer. Looking at the hg fetcher code, it seems built up in a way that should allow it, right down to the "supports_srcrev" function. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: Thanks for info! I think you should send a mail with request for clarification to openembedded mailing list. For example `rev` is described in context of git fetcher, only checking the sources on your own can tell you if this is also applicable for mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "tip" as source revision like:

```
SRCREV = "tip"
SRCMODULE = "myapp"
SRC_URI = "hg://hg_server_url;rev=${SRCREV};protocol=http;branch=${SRCBRANCH};module=${SRCMODULE}"
```

Keep only in mind (found that hard way) that **hg_server_url** shouldn't include target repo subname, but include it as ***SRCMODULE*** !

Comment: That's resolve conflict ONLY ONCE, so I'll make test with hard hacks like `do_install[nostamp] = "1"`